# Proof Check Sobolev $H^m(\Omega)$ and Riez representation.

Tags: functional-analysis, sobolev-spaces

Hello  I would like to check if the proof of the following propostion is correct

**Propostion** Show that for all $f \in (H^m(\Omega))'$ exist $f_\alpha \in L^2(\Omega)$, $|\alpha|\leq m$
$$f(v)= \sum_{|\alpha|\leq m} \int_{\Omega} f_\alpha \partial^\alpha v dx \quad \forall v \in H^m(\Omega).$$
**Proof**: By Riesz representation theorem exist $\tilde v \in H^m(\Omega)$
\begin{align}f(v) &= \langle\tilde v, v  \rangle_{H^m(\Omega)} \\
&= \sum_{|\alpha|\leq m} \int_{\Omega} \partial^\alpha \tilde v \cdot 
 \partial^\alpha v\ dx \quad \forall v \in H^m(\Omega),
\end{align}
where $\partial^\alpha \tilde v \in L^2(\Omega)$ so we can choose $f_\alpha:=\partial^\alpha \tilde v$ for all $|\alpha|\leq m$ and the proof is complete.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The proof seems correct to me. More general you can show an analogous result for the case $p \neq 2$ using that there exists a canonical isometric isomorphism
\begin{align}
j \colon \left(L^p(\Omega)^{|\alpha|}\right)^{'} \to L^{p'}(\Omega)^{|\alpha|}
\end{align}
and the fact that $W^{m,p}(\Omega)$ can be isometrically embedded into $L^p(\Omega)^{|\alpha|}$, where $|\alpha| \leq m$.